# How to get the date in my case using SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I don't know how ask this question.

I have two table **Transaction** and **Missing**

**Transaction**

```
id    Date
---------------
1     1-10-2016
2     2-10-2016
3     2-10-2016
6     5-10-2016
7     6-10-2016
8     7-10-2016
10    21-10-2016
16    23-10-2016
17    24-10-2016
```

**Missing**  (This is missing table it is having which is not in Transaction Table

```
ID
-----------
4
5
9
11
12
13
14
15
```

Now I want to show `Missing.ID and Date` like below

```
id    Date
---------------
4     2-10-2016  //(this date is date of Transaction.id 3's date)
5     2-10-2016  //(this date is date of Transaction.id 3's date)

9     7-10-2016  //(this date is date of Transaction.id 8's date)

11    21-10-2016  //(this date is date of Transaction.id 10's date)
12    21-10-2016  //(this date is date of Transaction.id 10's date)
13    21-10-2016  //(this date is date of Transaction.id 10's date)
14    21-10-2016  //(this date is date of Transaction.id 10's date)
15    21-10-2016  //(this date is date of Transaction.id 10's date)
```

If i want to join both table on which basis i can join?. There is no link between this table

Comment: Why ID 4 and 5 take `2-10-2016` and not other dates? based on what?

Comment: @Sami What is the previous ID's Date which is there in Transaction

Comment: JOIN ON MessingID = TransactionID - 1?

Comment: @Sami how will you calculate for ID = 15?. (15 - 1 = 14) that is also missing id

Comment: I was asking you there is that what you you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could combine your both table data (`Transaction`...`Missing`) using `union all` and use the combined result set to replace the `null` values with previous `date` column values based on `id`... And do the join operation as you want to display missing `ids` with `date` as follow

```
;with cte as
(
    select id, [Date] from Transaction
    union all
    select id, null [Date] from Missing 
)
select m.id, t.[Date] from Missing m
join 
(
      select id, case when c.[Date] is null then 
      (select top 1 [Date] from cte WHERE id < c.id and [Date] is not null order by id desc)
      else c.[Date] end [Date]   
      from cte C 
) t on m.id = t.id
```

Result :

```
id  date
4   2-10-2016
5   2-10-2016
9   7-10-2016
11  21-10-2016
12  21-10-2016
13  21-10-2016
14  21-10-2016
15  21-10-2016
```

Answer (score 3):

I suggest using an apply operator for this:

```
select id, ca.date
from missing
cross apply (
   select top(1) Transaction.date from Transaction
   where Transaction.id < missing.id
   order by Transaction.date DESC
   ) ca (date)
```

Comment: Please wait I am checking